# How to read a file that contains values of 12 different arrays in 4 lines?

Tags: python, file-read

I have a text file, where columns 6 to 9 represent values of some variables.  The 4 values (col:6 to 9) in the first line belongs to 4 `arrays(say a1, a2, a3, a4)`. Then the 4 on the second line to b1, b2, b3, b4 (say) and so on for `line:3 (c1 to c4)` and `line:4 (d1 to d4)`. lines 5 to 8 represent second element of these 16 arrays and so on.  The number of lines in the file is multiple of 4. How do I read such a text files and store the elements in variables?

The text files is created in Ansys APDL by another file. These values are required for further postprocessing of data.

The column 5 in the file contains: `1,4,8,11` in the same order till the EOF.  I have tried to search '1' in  column 5 and append 4 variables (a1 to a4), then search '4' in column 5 and append variables (b1 to b4) and so on. but this is very slow, especially when the length of file is too large.

```
FTSIZE,   1,   1,18593                     
FP, 1,  10.000    ,  20.000    ,  50.000    ,  100.00    ,  200.00    
FP, 6,  500.00    ,  1000.0    ,  2000.0    ,  5000.0    ,  10000.    
FP,11,  20000.    ,  50000.    , 0.10000E+06, 0.20000E+06, 0.50000E+06
FP,16, 0.10000E+07, 0.20000E+07, 0.50000E+07, 0.10000E+09, 0.10000E+12
FP,21,  6000.0    ,  4300.0    ,  2748.0    ,  1978.0    ,  1440.0    
FP,26,  974.00    ,  745.00    ,  590.00    ,  450.00    ,  368.00    
FP,31,  300.00    ,  235.00    ,  196.00    ,  168.00    ,  142.00    
FP,36,  126.00    ,  113.00    ,  102.00    ,  97.000    ,  93.000    
FS,       1,   1,   1, 1, -9.9985    ,  1.0121    ,  12.023    ,  0.0000    
FS,       1,   1,   1, 4, 0.14230E-10,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  317.10    
FS,       1,   1,   1, 8,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    
FS,       1,   1,   1,11,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    
FS,       1,   1,   2, 1, -9.9996    ,  1.0245    ,  12.597    ,  0.0000    
FS,       1,   1,   2, 4, 0.46318E-11,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  317.10    
FS,       1,   1,   2, 8,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    
FS,       1,   1,   2,11,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  0.0000    ,  0.0000
```

for this file I would expect: 
`a1 = -9.9985, -9.9996;  a2 = 1.0121, 1.0245; a3 = 12.023, 12.597` and so on. The initial 9 lines has to be skipped as well.

Comment: If you know how to read the file, use split(",") if its the delimitator and not appears in value, then extract values in that list

Comment: The required values do not appear line by line.  If I use split, I will get only 4 arrays but not 16.

Comment: 1) The required values do not appear line by line. ???? They appear in the file? I dont understand your answer. 2)Split dont return arrays, it return only 1 array with multiples elements, so what do you means?? post how are you trying to read the file...

Comment: There are 16  values of variables in 4 lines of the file.  They constitute first element of 16 arrays.  The next 4 lines of the file constitute second element of the same 16 arrays and it goes on like this. So basically I need to read 4 lines in group and store 16 elements and then read next 4 lines.

Comment: Then reduce your problems one by one, if you know how to readlines() it will be an array, then group them as you want. Then focus in the problem of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, but this will put the data from columns 6 to 9 into a list of lists grouping the data every four lines, skipping the first 9 lines.

```py
import itertools

with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

lines = [item.split(',')[5:8] for item in data.replace(' ','').split('\n')[9:]]
output = []
for x in range(len(lines)):
    if x % 4 == 0:
        output.append(list(itertools.chain(*output[x-4:x])))
```

Note that this assumes after the first 9 lines, the number of lines will be a multiple of 4. Also it strips out the whitespace from the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
a1, a2, a3= [], [], []
    with open("file.txt") as f:
        for _ in range(16):
            next(f)
        for count, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
            if (count % 4) - 1 == 0:
                a1.append(line.split(",")[5])
                a2.append(line.split(",")[6])
                a3.append(line.split(",")[7])
```

This can be used to solve this